# wp_insert_post() Returns Action failed. Please refresh the page and retry

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to create a new Wordpress Post using `wp_insert_post()` within a Wordpress Plug-in for a AJAX call. I have inspected that the related parametrs are pasing to the function but as my response I am getting  **Action failed. Please refresh the page and retry** and this is upon  `wp_insert_post()`.

**EDIT: I have checked the database and all the data stored properly in the database**

Also I tried the `wp_send_json( get_post(27538) ); die;` and it works fine within the same function.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_create_new_estimate', 'tcf_et_create_new_estimate' );
function tcf_et_create_new_estimate()
{
    $project_name   = $_REQUEST['project_name'];
    $email_address  = $_REQUEST['email_address'];
    $ikea_system    = $_REQUEST['ikea_system'];
    $project_notes  = $_REQUEST['project_notes'];

    $user       = get_user_by( 'email', $email_address );
    $user_id    = is_int( $user->ID ) ? $user->ID : 1;

    $wishlist_data = array(
        'post_type'    => 'wishlist',
        'post_title'   => sanitize_text_field( $project_name ),
        'post_content' => $project_notes,
        'post_status'  => 'publish',
        'ping_status'  => 'closed',
        'post_excerpt' => '',
        'post_author'  => $user_id
    );

    // die('here'); --> THIS CODE WORKS AND IT RETUNS "here" AS RESPONCE IF UNCOMMENTED
    $webhook_id = wp_insert_post( $wishlist_data );
    wp_send_json( $webhook_id );
    die;
}
```

Is there anything to pass for the `wp_insert_post()` than above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was I am trying to add `'post_type'    => 'wishlist'` before the `wishlist` is registered.